# Split string by N symbols in Python from the end of the string

Tags: python

I need to split the string from the end.
For example, I have

```
word = '3640000'
```

And it is easy to split it from the begin of the string using list generator and .join method:

```
word = ' '.join([word[i:i + 3] for i in range(0, len(word), 3)])
```

In this case I get result: '364 000 0'

but I need get: "3 640 000"

How can I solve this task?

I tried something like this, but it is not working for me if a word is not divisible by 3 without remainder

```
list1 = []
for i in range(len(word) - 1, -1, -3):
    print(word[i-2:i+1])
    list1.append(word[i-2:i+1])
list1.reverse()
```

Comment: Is this just for integer strings or any string of  arbitrary characters?

Comment: @snakecharmerb in my case it is only integer strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit hacky, we can use Python's string formatting to do the grouping, then replace the separator (Python only allows "," and "_" as grouping characters).

```
>>> w = '3640000'
>>> f'{int(w):,d}'.replace(',', ' ')
'3 640 000'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat inefficient, but based on what you did initially, you can reverse the word and then split/join with spaces, then reverse it back:

```
word = '3640000'
word = word[::-1]
word = ' '.join([word[i:i + 3] for i in range(0, len(word), 3)])
print(word[::-1])
```

Where `n` is 3 in this example.

Answer (score 1):

If you take the first part that is irregular first, it allows you to process the remaining part from front to back without hacks as before.

Use the modulo operator `%` to calculate the required length for the first part:

```
first_length = len(word) % 3
if first_length > 0:
    result = word[:first_length] + ' '
else:
    result = ''
result += ' '.join(word[i:i+3] for i in range(first_length, len(word), 3))
```

This can be made somewhat more generic and elegant by writing a generator function:

```
def split_from_right(word, n):
    first_length = len(word) % n
    if first_length > 0:
        yield word[:first_length]
    for i in range(first_length, len(word), n):
        yield word[i:i + n]

result = ' '.join(split_from_right(word, 3))
```